# constructor inheritance and polymorphism when privately inheriting

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm facing a bit of a puzzle with inheritance. I'm using c++ 20.
If i make 2 classes (Base -> Child1), where one inherits from the other, and make the inheritance itself private, but still declare the constructors publicly inherited, then this piece of code doesn't compile:

https://godbolt.org/z/6z9P6svPv

```
#include <iostream>

class Base { };

class FirstChild : private Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

void foo(Base* base) {
    std::cout << "Not ok!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto derived = new FirstChild();
    foo(derived);
}
```

However if i go through one more inheritance (Base -> Child1 -> Child2), and despite my IDE (Clion) shouting at me that this is an error, it seems to compile and work just fine.

https://godbolt.org/z/nMdf5v7Y5

```
#include <iostream>

class Base { };

class FirstChild : public Base { };

class SecondChild : private FirstChild {
public:
    using FirstChild::Base;
};

void foo(Base* base) {
    std::cout << "Ok!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto derived = new SecondChild();
    foo(derived);
}
```

I'm not sure what's the problem. Why does the second piece of code work but the first one doesn't? And is the second one actually correct? It does compile, but as i said, my IDE isn't very happy with it.

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited (since they aren't members - they belong to the class, rather than instances, and it's like that because there isn't a usable instance yet). Private and protected inheritance are tricky, and not as useful as you might think. First check if https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance answers your question.

Comment: The problem i'm facing is that i'm trying to hide some functionality of the base class. Therefore i want to declare the inheritance private and then selectively make only certain methods public/protected. The other way around - inheriting publicly and then marking methods that are not supposed to be seen as private would be a lot harder to maintain in my case. Composition is also not something that would work very well in my case. After reading through the article i'm honestly still not sure what exactly is going on in my example. I'd expect either both examples to work or neither of them.

Comment: In the most derived class, make a public function that just thunks to the base class function.  If you can make it implicitly inline, even better.

Comment: If you’re using private inheritance, maybe you should look at encapsulation instead